# ¿Cómo prevenir un Bad State: Cannot add new events after calling close?

Tags: flutter

Llamar al método **isClosed** es la mejor manera de prevenir la excepción de Bad State:  Cannot add new events after calling close.

Tengo algunos futures, que son llamadas al servicio (api), y luego agrego datos al stream (_personController) pero en algunos casos puede que el usuario cambie de pantalla y el controlador ya fue cerrado

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
class PersonBloc {
  final PersonProvider _personProvider = PersonProvider();

  final BehaviorSubject<Person> _personController = BehaviorSubject<Person>();
  Function(Person) get personSink => _personController.sink.add;
  Stream<Person> get personStream => _personController.stream;

  Future<void> dispose() async {
    _personController?.close();
  }

  Future<void> list() async {
      final person = await _personProvider.fetchList();
      if (!_personController.isClosed) {
        personSink(person);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: con la validación que haces no te funciona ?

Comment: si, si funciona, pero no sé si es lo mejor, porque por cada stream habría que hacer lo mismo

Comment: Esa es la forma ya que tu llamada es asincrona, la respuesta podría venir cuando el widger ya fue sacado del arbol, se que te parece muy trabajoso rxdart y streams, te recomiendo que veas este playslist que tenemos https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYZSbh8amjElmFAbXirjMp3N8DzxgrP_C

Comment: Gracias excelente contenido en el canal